# Nginx rewrite for image direct access in browser url

Tags: nginx

I was trying and unable to get working rewrite rule.
i want the image to be included in any website. But when the image is directly accessed in the browser url, i want the rewrite to happen.

http://i683.photobucket.com/albums/vv191/angelinesona/Animhorse.gif

As an example, Photobucket has done this. We can include this image in our website with img src tag. But if you try to access this image via url, it will redirect to the original page.

How can we detect whether the image is directly accessed without using img tag or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the `Accept` header. That’s apparently also what Photobucket does. If it contains `text/html`, serve HTML. Otherwise the browser is probably looking for an image. It’s supposed to send `image/*` then, but that doesn’t work for me on some machines (Firefox on Linux).

Photobucket also looks at the User Agent string, to identify download-only clients like cURL.

Obviously, all this isn’t very reliable. But keep in mind: It’s better if the embed works but your redirect doesn’t. If it’s the other way around, user experience will suffer a lot more.